# TypeError: press() missing 1 required positional argument: 'button'

Tags: python

I was testing this functions for another python script, but when I executed them I got an error

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
import webbrowser
import time

def moveMouseAndClick():
    url = "Secret"
    webbrowser.open(url)
    mouse = Controller()
    time.sleep(4.5)
    mouse.position = (1094.59, 153.52)
    time.sleep(1)
    mouse.press(Button.left)
    mouse.release(Button.left)

def login():
    keyboard = Controller()
    keyboard.type("Secret")
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)

moveMouseAndClick()
time.sleep(2)
login()
```

output:

```
TypeError: AttributeError: 'Controller' object has no attribute 'type'
```

So I made a few changes, but I got another error

```
from pynput.keyboard import Controller as Ctrll_1
from pynput.mouse import Controller as Ctrll_2
from pynput.keyboard import Key
from pynput.mouse import Button
import webbrowser
import time

def moveMouseAndClick():
    url = "Secret"
    webbrowser.open(url)
    mouse = Ctrll_2
    time.sleep(4.5)
    mouse.position = (1094.59, 153.52)
    time.sleep(1)
    mouse.press(Button.left)
    mouse.release(Button.left)

def login():
    keyboard = Ctrll_1
    keyboard.type("Secret")
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)

moveMouseAndClick()
time.sleep(2)
login()
```

output:

```
TypeError: press() missing 1 required positional argument: 'button'
```

I'm a beginner in python so I'm completely lost, any help or advice will be great thanks!

Comment: This might help `mouse = Ctrll_2()`

Comment: `press()` method needs positional argument named 'button'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for that error is it's because `mouse.Controller` which in this case is `Ctrll_2`
is a class variable not a function so you should've defined initiated it before using it.
the problem will happen at `keyboard.Controller` which is `Ctrll_1`

here is the fixed code that should be working fine in your case

```py
from pynput.keyboard import Controller as Ctrll_1
from pynput.mouse import Controller as Ctrll_2
from pynput.keyboard import Key
from pynput.mouse import Button
import webbrowser
import time

def moveMouseAndClick():
    url = "http://google.com"
    webbrowser.open(url)
    mouse = Ctrll_2()
    time.sleep(4.5)
    mouse.position = (1094.59, 153.52)
    time.sleep(1)
    mouse.press(Button.left)
    mouse.release(Button.left)

def login():
    keyboard = Ctrll_1()
    keyboard.type("password")
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)

moveMouseAndClick()
time.sleep(2)
login()
```

Answer (score -1):

1. in mouse.press(Button.left), you should insert all button arguments. https://pypi.org/project/mouse/

Comment: OP is clearly using different module - pynput, this answer is not helpful.

Comment: Please use english here on stackoverflow, and check accepted answer, you will see it is not the module you link.

Comment: It's not a incorrect answer, it's about learning how to evaluate global errors, not getting your code done.